# Why I'm not able to show second modal dialog after closing the first modal dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm using **Bootstrap v3.3.5** for my website.

I've a following HTML code of first bootstrap modal dialog :

```
<div style="display: block;" id="myModal-event" class="modal fade in" role="dialog">
  <div role="document" style="width:600px;position:relative;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;">
    <div class="modal-content" style="border:0;"> 
      <div style="margin-top: 10px;" role="document" class="modal-dialog event-planner">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 id="myModalLabel" class="modal-title">Event Details</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="event-title">
                NewDemoEvent5
                <input name="hid_event_id" id="hid_event_id" value="501" type="hidden">
                </div>
                <ul id="popover-content" class="list-group" style="display: none">
                  <a href="#" data-target="#myModal-edit-event" class="list-group-item" id="edit-event">Edit Event</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Invite Members</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Delete Event</a>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When user clicks on menu hyperlink **"Edit Event"** the above modal dialog should get close and a new modal dialog should get open.

Following is the HTML of  new modal dialog :

```
<div id="myModal-edit-event" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div role="document" style="width:600px;position:relative;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;">
    <div class="modal-content" style="border:0;">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 id="myModalLabel" class="modal-title">Event Details</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"> Loading Mannu... </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm able to close the first modal dialog upon clicking on "Edit Event" hyperlink but I'm not able to open up a new second modal dialog.

I tried below code :

```
$('#myModal-event').on('click', '#edit-event', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.modal').modal('hide');
  $('#myModal-edit-event').modal('show');
});
```

Also, some other script used for some other functionality gets executed. I strongly think that it is affecting my code as well. That script is as below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '#myModal-event', function () {
    console.log('Hi *');
    $("#myModal-event .modal-body").html(' Loading... ');
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');    
    });
});
```

In above script I want to know whether the execution stops after the statement `console.log('Hi *');` and the last two statements doesn't get execute.

Some one please help me in my issue.

Thanks.

Comment: just throwing this out there.... when you do get this working ... your UX design is going to be a nightmare for users to hit browser back and forward buttons expecting to switch between modals .   I have ran into the same thing.   Also SEO is going to be a nightmare if you are putting details into modals and want search engines to index these details that are only avaliable through modals

Answer (score 2):

In JS Script following line may cause the 2nd modal not show because it has `.modal` class which is common in both modals

```
 $(this).closest('.modal').modal('hide');
```

and 2nd reason may be there is no `data-toggle` attribute in `<a>` tag which opens the 2nd modal.

```
<a href="#" data-target="#myModal-edit-event" class="list-group-item" id="edit-event">Edit Event</a>
```

both data attributes `data-toggle` and `data-target` are necessary, one will not work without other.

**For Simple Approach to close First modal and open Second modal**

Remove  `href="#" data-target="#myModal-edit-event" id="edit-event"` from `<a>` tag

No need of click function

```
$('#myModal-event').on('click', '#edit-event', function (event) {
});
```

Simple close first modal with data attribute `data-dismiss="modal"`

```
<a data-dismiss="modal" class="list-group-item">Edit Event</a>
```

Use Modal Event `hidden.bs.modal` to open 2nd modal once first modal closed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myModal-event').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#myModal-edit-event').modal('show');
     });
});
```

Working Example

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#myModal-event').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#myModal-edit-event').modal('show');
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-event">Open Modal</button>
<div id="myModal-event" class="modal fade in" role="dialog">
  <div role="document" style="width:600px;position:relative;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;">
    <div class="modal-content" style="border:0;"> 
      <div style="margin-top: 10px;" role="document" class="modal-dialog event-planner">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 id="myModalLabel" class="modal-title">Event Details</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="event-title">
                NewDemoEvent5
                <input name="hid_event_id" id="hid_event_id" value="501" type="hidden">
                </div>
                <ul id="popover-content" class="list-group" style="display: none">
                  <a data-dismiss="modal">Edit Event</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Invite Members</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Delete Event</a>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal-edit-event" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div role="document" style="width:600px;position:relative;margin:auto;margin-top:10px;">
    <div class="modal-content" style="border:0;">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 id="myModalLabel" class="modal-title">Event Details</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"> Loading Mannu... </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

SideNote: you have this repeating `modal-content` class in First Modal

```
<div class="modal-content" style="border:0;"> 
  <div style="margin-top: 10px;" role="document" class="modal-dialog event-planner">
    <div class="modal-content">
    //Rest of the Modal Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your immense help and thoughtful guidance. But still the issue persists. I tried exactly the code you used in the answer. First modal dialog get closed when I click on Edit Event link but then the second modal dialog doesn't get open  and a black-out faded screen appeared. I checked in the console as well. It showed the string 'Hi *'. That indicates the code which I put at the end of my question is getting executed. Is that code preventing next modal dialog from opening up? I'd be thankful to you if you could guide me & solve issue. Thanks again. Waiting for your reply.

Comment: Even I tried by putting the code  $('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '#myModal-event', function () {
    console.log('Hi *');
    $("#myModal-event .modal-body").html(' Loading... ');
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');    
    }); inside comments but still the black-faded out screen appears after closing the first modal dialog and second modal dialog doesn't get open. I've become clue less now. Also the is no error, no output data in firebug console.

Comment: Add class 'modal-dialog' before 'modal-content' in 2nd modal and see if it makes a difference and also check both modals all div close properly

Comment: I tried adding the class 'modal-dialog'  before 'modal-content' in 2nd modal . But still same is the result.

Comment: 2 options, 1 if you have live link, share so have closer look, 2. if localhost, create a http://pastebin.com/ of code (preferable HTML code) and share the link here will check the code

Answer (score 0):

**Try the following solution.**

```
$('#edit-event').on('click', function(){
    /* Hide event modal */
    $('#myModal-event').modal('hide');

    /* Show edit event modal */
    $('#myModal-edit-event').modal('show');
});
```